# Decidability of L

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

I have the following problem. If L is decidable and L = L1 u L2 (union). So are L1 and L2 decidable, too?

I know that, if L is decidable, the complement is also. And this means the complement is recursively enumerable. How can I proof it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $L_1$ be the halting problem and $L_2 = \overline{L_1}$. The union of
$L_1$ and $L_2$ is $\Sigma^*$, which is decidable, while $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not.